# Jquery: why $("#id_pop")[0] is illegal?

Tags: jquery

In my code when I write code like:

```
$("#id_pop")[0]
```

there is an error. When I correct it to:

```
var $d = $("#id_pop");
$d[0]....
```

it's ok. Why?

Comment: use `$("#id_pop").first()` or `$("#id_pop").get(0)` I've run into `[0]` problems before. I don't remember what it was, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[0]` should work, i.e. get you a DOM object. But you can't continue using jQuery methods once you get back a normal DOM object.

you can also get a DOM object from a jQuery selector like this:

`$('#id_pop').get(0);`

Also are you sure you only have one element with the id `id_pop`. If there is then `$('#id_pop')[0]` should work.

See working example here: http://jsbin.com/udace3

Comment: I see! so $d is still an jquery object but if I only get it from [0] it is a normal dom object, that is why the error is happening.

Comment: @BinChen when you inspected the return object of $('#id_pop') using any debugger avaible (im using visual studio) you can see that the returning object is indeed a jQuery object and have the element selected in and array, so if the selector used it will returns more objects this array will hold them. So basically $("")[0] is accessing the array where the first object will be the one with the id="#id_pop". So is a Dom Object what jQuery do with the .get(0) method is access that array and return also the jQuery Object for mantain chainability.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an ID selector, you should not be getting an array but the jquery object itself.  In the jQuery documentation of using the #id,

*Each id should only be used only once within a document.  If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM. This behavior should not be relied on...*

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it better to use .eq() instead of .get()?

```
$('#id_pop').eq(0);
```

Or for that matter:

```
$('#id_pop:eq(0)');
```

Comment: both of these are still jQuery objects and not plain JS DOM objects

Comment: True, but he's using jQuery, so I suggested it.